# Why doesn't my hyperlinks text color change?

Tags: html, css

After trying multiple time i still have failed to change the text color. I have put the  in the  to get them to line up, I don't know if this would be causing the problem though.
Here is my CSS code for my link.

```css
a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #54b3d6,
    #54b3d6 50%,
    #000 50%
  );
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: -100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

a:before {
  content: '';
  background: #54b3d6;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover {
 background-position: 0;
}

a:hover::before {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hello World</a>
```

I have tried everything I could, I tried changing the  text color and the nav text color. Usually the a {} should work but this time it didn't

Comment: think it's because  ```text-decoration: none;```

Comment: Code is working for me when I made it runnable. What is not working for you?

Comment: The text color won't change to white

Comment: because the backround-image is controlling your color

Comment: I tried removing that and it still hasn't worked

Comment: I am trying to change the color before the animation

Answer (score 0):

background image is set to black and that is controlling what color it is. Changing it to white and it will become white.

```css
background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #54b3d6,
    #54b3d6 50%,
    #000 50%
  );
```

```css
a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #54b3d6,
    #54b3d6 50%,
    #FFF 50%
  );
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: -100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

a:before {
  content: '';
  background: #54b3d6;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover {
 background-position: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hello World</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `-webkit-text-fill-color` css property, it specifies the color of the text no matter the value that you set in the `color` property. So you need to set the color that you want there or just remove that property the value of the `color` property is used.

set this:

```
a {
  color: #fff;
  /* other properties*/
  -webkit-text-fill-color: red;
}
```

or this:

```
a {
    color: red;
    /* other properties*/
}
```

---

Demo:

```css
a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #54b3d6,
    #54b3d6 50%,
    #000 50%
  );
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: -100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  /*-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;*/
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

a:before {
  content: '';
  background: #54b3d6;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover {
 background-position: 0;
}

a:hover::before {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hello World</a>
```